# Why unity3d apps are big size?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have just made a very basic 3D app on unity3D basic version. It has one plane, 3 cubes and 1 FPC. And the built file is around 10mb. Why the file is so big ? Is it possible to reduce the size ? I am planning to make apps for android, hence I need to know how to keep the file size minimum.

Comment: I would just not use Unity :P Is it a strict requirement to use it or are there any alternatives you can use? (OpenGL java bindings for instance)

Comment: @JesusRamos could u please elaborate why u would not recommend unity ? using unity one can develop faster.

Comment: Faster is not always better especially if you're looking for small executable/package size and flexibility. Depending on what you're doing Unity may or may not be a very good option.

Comment: I understand what you are talking about. But can unity apps be optimised for size ? If I use opengl then building physics effects, textures etc will consume a lot of time.

Comment: Not from what I've seen. There are other things you can use on top of OpenGL or DirectX if you want but Unity just feels too clunky. Importing models is a nightmare (it doesn't give you errors, just gives you broken mesh data). They produce quite large executables as you saw. And it forces you to do things their way with no way around it (makes version control a nightmare sometimes with random files popping in and out of existence). That being said you can throw stuff together very quickly though.

Comment: It's also not difficult to write a small engine for yourself depending on what you're doing. There are also some physics libraries out there that you can use if you dont like math.

Comment: @JesusRamos so how much reduction in size can i expect from opengl for above app ?

Comment: Depending on the language written (excluding asset size) you could get quite a small application. I've written simple engines that are a lot smaller than 10mb, heck smaller than 1mb in most cases that do exactly what I need them to do rather than 5 things I need and a million I don't. If you only want a 3d app (I saw you asked a question about a 3d launcher) there's no point to using unity at least in my opinion.

Comment: @JesusRamos that was great reply. And you are correct I am thinking of 3D launcher app with physics. Do you think opengl is good for this purpose or you recommend something else. Btw do you have any idea what they have used to make https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spb.shell3d

Comment: For android I think opengl is your best bet for that. I don't know if there are any engines or such for building applications but something like that shouldn't be difficult after a tutorial or two on 3d programming.

Comment: Take a look at the descriptions of the different version on the unity page! With UnityPro it's supported, that all unneeded content is stripped out while compiling, while the basic version simply includes the whole framework

Comment: @J.Starkl do you have any idea how much above app will become in size

Comment: This will depend on what you use from the framework, there is no general answer

Comment: The [docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html) may help (there's also some [hints for iPhone](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/iphone-playerSizeOptimization.html)) and you've asked in the wrong place. I hope my right placed similar question do get answered tho: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/534833/building-a-very-small-sized-app-to-less-than-5mb.html

Comment: The Unity dev blogs indicate that they are working to modularize Unity so that unneeded parts wont be included in builds. So you can look forward to smaller builds in the future, but may have to wait for Unity 5.0 or later.

Comment: Whenever you build a Unity3D app, it includes all of files/directories required to run the app in the `appname_data` and `MonoBleedingEdge` directories. These take up space as well.

Comment: I don't think 10mb is much to worry about.